# get something kick out of somebody meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, slang, metaphors

> Look guys, for thousands of years, guys like us, have gotten the sh*t kicked out of us.

I looked up this in idioms' and slangs' dictionary but they have only mentioned "get a kick out of something" which means "enjoying something".
Would you please inform me on this?

Sorry for the crude example, by the way, I just had no idea whether removing it would have an effect on its meaning. the above sentence then goes on like this in case that you need a wider context:

> ...but now, we're living in an era that we can be in charge and make our own empires.

I think he's going to say we should not waste this opportunity by our own hands, we should not turn down this pleasure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Get the shit kicked out of somebody

means the same as:

> get the crap kicked out of (someone)

that is:

> To be struck or assaulted violently and severely.

In this context it also implies being abused (not specifically phisycally)

So, after "thousands of years" - an immeasurably long period of time,
they should, exactly as you say, grab the opportunity and enjoy the moment while it lasts.

Answer (score 2):

You'll usually see this phrased as:

> *kick the* _______ *out of something*

where some expletive goes in the blank. For example, I might say:

> I'm going to kick the crap out of my roommate when he gets back home.

Most often, this would refer to physical violence against a person, although it's possible that it could be used more metaphorically to refer to something like a harsh scolding.

You might also use the phrase to say that you've struggled with something and emerged triumphant, like a [test](https://books.google.com/books?id=ys_xe0lPUosC&dq=kicked%20the%20shit%20out%20of%20my%20test&source=gbs_navlinks_s):

> I kicked the snot out of that exam this morning!

(If someone said that, I would assume they felt like they did very well.)

Or you could be referring to a physical assault on an inanimate object:

> We beat the crap out of a 'ShatterProof' iPhone with hammers.
>   <sub>([News headline](http://www.businessinsider.com/amzer-shatterproof-video-test-2013-10))</sub>

The version you've cited is inverted – the speaker is not the person who is doing the figurative kicking; rather it's the person who is being kicked. (This may be why it was hard to find in the dictionary. The version I've cited can be found in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-beat-kick-or-knock-the-shit-out-of-someone) and [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kick+the+crap+out+of).)

> *For thousands of years, guys like us have gotten the sh*t kicked out of us*.

This means other people of been giving "guys like us" a beat-down for a very long time.

Comment: I wonder if the question about ["science the crap out of..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82726/) would be relevant, or if "kick the crap out of" is something different because there's no verbing.