# is it idiomatic to mix expressions "to nail something" and "the sh* out of"?

Tags: idioms, slang

The expression **to nail something** usually means to "to achieve something or do something right". (informal)

The expression "the sh*t out of" is used to "emphasize the degree of force of an action that you are describing" (Cambridge)

I was wondering if it sounded natural to native speakers to say, "nail the sh*t out of something", essentially mixing the two expressions to sound more emphatic, as in:

> She nailed the shit out of the chorus
>
> he nailed the shit out of writing that piece of code.

Comment: You can say what you want. Would other native speakers say this? I doubt it very much. "He nailed it" is an expression on its own

Comment: Normally "the shit out of" is used to describe a violent act.  *The hoodlums  beat the shit out of the shop owner and stole all the money from the cash register.*  You won't hear it on the evening news.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo _Scare the shit out of_ is also used not to mention [_Sam Smith promises 'sing the sh*t out of the next 2 years' at comeback ..._](http://metro.co.uk/2017/11/04/sam-smith-promises-to-sing-the-sht-out-of-the-next-two-years-as-he-wows-at-emotional-comeback-gig-7053505/) in the Metro news

Comment: **beat the shit out of** and **scare the shit out of** have been around for quite a long time, since the 1950s at least; but **sing the shit out of** is a more recent collocation.

Comment: Related: [“(Noun) the sh*t out of this” — What nouns work?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82726/)

Comment: I suppose that's today's teen slang.  It's a fairly recent thing to use **{verb} the shit out of** to mean "did a really great job {verb-ing}"

Comment: It seems to me you'd be conflating two idioms to use it that way.

Comment: @ShahabSamkan - you cannot get a straight answer to your question. To me it reads really annoying and not a clever or funny version of "nailing it" but yes, you are free to say it and most English native speakers and some non-natives would understand the marriage between two expressions - it does not mean it will sound good. It is syntactically sound.

Comment: @ShahabSamkan - You don't like this website? That's okay, I don't like your attitude. We don't exist to serve you, we don't get paid to do this; answers and comments on ELL are given freely by helpful people out of their own goodwill. You are free to find somewhere else to ask your questions if you don't like the service you get here. You won't be missed. By the way, did you ever think that one reason it's so hard to get a straight answer is because English rules are so flexible? Maybe it's not a community problem, maybe your beef is really with the language.

Comment: While you could say this, some listeners might think you're trying to make a sexual allusion.  The verb "to nail" is well-known slang for having sex with someone (particularly if it's a man doing the "nailing"), and the idiom "to fuck the shit out of" is also well-known.  This could result in significant misinterpretations of your meaning.

Comment: @Shahab - If you’re getting info that you already know in comments, that usually means you haven’t shared enough of what you know in your question. (We sometimes call this “prior research” or simply “details” – more on that [**here**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439).) I urge you to read your question as if you’re reading it for the first time – how easy would it be for anyone to discern what you already realize, and what you want more help with? There is no background or motivation provided! As for liking the website, you have a funny way of sharing that (this website sucks?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that **you can't**.

When using *to nail something*, it is always structured like:

> I nailed that solo.

Here nailed is the verb, while I and solo are respectively subject and object.

Using *verbing the shit out of something* results in the following structure:

> You scared the shit out of me.

Here scared is the verb, thus emphasizing the scaring.

So saying that you *nailed the shit out of something* would be the same as saying that you *did a great job nailing something*.