# What part of speech is "daily" in the phrase "on the daily"?

Tags: word-usage, slang

I read a sentence which was:

> They do it **on the daily**.

Consider the part "on the daily".
Daily is a noun as it is preceded by a preposition. 
But most of the dictionaries define "daily" as a noun as either a newspaper or any servant. 
So, how do you interpret this?

Comment: *On the daily*, in that context, is not normal. Taking that sentence on its own, it should be simply *They do it daily*.

Comment: Can you tell us where you came across the sentence - in what context?

Comment: @JasonBassford “On the daily” is slang for every day as in [how many mics do we rip **on the daily**](http://www.metrolyrics.com/how-many-mics-lyrics-the-fugees.html)

Comment: Isn't it "on the daily basis" with "basis" dropped?

Comment: @Kreiri No, it would be “on **a** daily basis”.

Comment: I came across this sentence in a video on elephant trunk https://youtu.be/DjpRgi-73bU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On the daily** and **on the regular** are both slang phrases that mean **on a regular basis**.  This [English StackExchange discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399535/he-contradicts-himself-on-the-regular) dives into **on the regular** a bit, and someone mentions **on the daily** in the comments.  Both slang phrases seem to originate largely from hip-hop culture (or at least that seems to be their vector into the mainstream).  Another example, from the Black-Eyed Peas' ["My Humps"](https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20humps%20lyrics):

> I drive these brothers crazy,
>   I do it on the daily.

It is not "standard" English to use an adjective as a noun, so this phrase should not be used in formal written English and should probably be avoided by most learners, but native speakers have certainly encountered slang uses of adjectives in the place of nouns in other situations (e.g., "I have a sad!" - incorrect, but very common on the internet).

Comment: One of the more entertaining parts of English is how easily we can change the syntactic role of pretty much any word. Related question: [(Noun) the sh*t out of this” — What nouns work?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82726/9161)