# Using "snow job" as a verb

Tags: word-usage, verbing

Merriam-Webster defines "snow job" as a noun.

Is there any chance I can get away with using it as a verb?

As in, "He thought he could snow-job her into going along with his scheme."

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["(Noun) the sh\*t out of this" — What nouns work?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82726/noun-the-sht-out-of-this-what-nouns-work) I know that isn't your exact sentence, but the answers explain when we can use a noun as a verb and might be helpful.

Comment: No hard cites, only anecdotal info, so not good for an answer here. Nevertheless, in some areas (including NYC) it's not unusual to hear phrases like ***Don't try to snow me; I know better***.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I have also heard "snow" as a verb for piling on the words in order to mislead or deceive. [Random House, Collins and American Heritage dictionaries list "snow" as a transitive verb](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/being+snowed) : *10. Slang. to persuade or deceive by insincere talk or flattery.*

Comment: @ColleenV - Yes, that's also a common usage; the usage I gave is more-or-less a short form of ***Don't try to pull a snow job on me; I know better***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How "fast and loose" you can be with English depends on your audience. Because I'm online, I could easily look up ***snow job*** when I saw this question - but if OP had just used it in a conversation down the pub, for example, I'd have had to ask what he meant.

But that's nothing to do with whether ***snow job*** was used as a noun or verb (or adjective - *That was a snow-job response* is perfectly credible). The basic principle in English is that almost *all* nouns can be used as verbs - *if that makes sense*.

It doesn't really matter whether the dictionary specifically says your noun is also a verb. Native speakers just *speak* - they don't keep checking a dictionary to see if they're allowed to say something.

---

I appreciate that non-native speakers won't necessarily have the confidence to take this position. But they can always search Google Books - here are plenty of written instances of [***snow-jobbed***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22snow%20jobbed%22) (sometimes hyphenated, sometimes not; that's just a stylistic choice).